# Format asp table cell text

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, html-table, formatting

I wish to apply text colouring to only part of a ASP.net table cell's text value.

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
    string BeneficiaryName = "ABCD";
    string status = "Active";
    tblcell = new TableCell();

   if(status == "Active")
   {
     tblcell.Text = BeneficiaryName + " " + status  ;
   }
```

This sets the cell text to have both BenficiaryName and status variables combined, but I want the "status" value to appear with a green colour.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: reworded to better explain what the OP wants to achieve and added a relevant tag

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a style directly to the text.

```
tblcell.Text = BeneficiaryName + " <span style='color: green;'>" + status + "</span>";
```